# Programmatically add EC2 execute nodes to Grid Engine cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, gridengine

I am running Grid Scheduler (fka Sun Grid Engine) on Amazon Web Services. Master node is running all the time, but I want to programmatically add nodes to the cluster (also remove - but remove is not a problem).

I launch an instance from existing AMI; during startup it POSTs it's hostname (say ip-10-11-12-13) to the master node. So, if I were doing it manually, I'd run `qconf -ae` and fill the template with the hostname. I would also run `qconf -mconf all.q` and add the new host and its number of core to the SLOTS statement.

I guess I can build a file and use `qconf -Ae fname` and `qconf -Mconf file_list`. Is there a way to do such updates without awk/sed file tinkering?

Edit: I am familiar with MIT StarCluster; but for variety of reasons we are not using it.